# This question has an open bounty and can't be closed - duplicate?

Tags: discussion, bounties, duplicate-questions

I put a bounty on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114163/schannel-ssl-implementation), because there wasn't any obvious solution. However, recently I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032056/compilable-c-code-to-implement-a-secure-sll-tls-client-using-ms-sspi). But I can't mark it as a duplicate since I put on the bounty. What should I do?

Comment: @Sebastian Simon Does that work?

Comment: I've done that mutiple times, so yes, that works. Here is an example question I flagged: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56275314/revisions and where a mod removed and returned the bounty and closed the question.